# Blurry Screen on Correct Resolution with New Monitor

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, hdmi

Edit: using Ubuntu 20.04
I believe I'm running XServer and not wayland. By getting my session ID from `loginctl` which is 2, and running: `loginctl show-session 2 -p Type` the output I get this: `Type=x11`.

Been struggling with this for some time. I've tried updating the dpi on my monitor and adjusting for a new mode but the text on my new Msi Optix G24 series monitor (`DP-0 connected primary 1920x1080+3840+0`) with 144 Hz refresh rate is still blurry, while the text on my previous monitor that I've hooked up to a dual display (`HDMI-0 connected 3840x2160+0+0`)

Here is the output from `xrandr`:

```
(base) john@john-linux:~$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 5760 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 connected primary 1920x1080+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 520mm x 290mm
   1920x1080     60.00 + 143.85   119.98    59.94    50.00* 
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1440x576      50.00  
   1440x480      59.94  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 621mm x 341mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    30.00    29.97    25.00    23.98  
   2560x1600     59.97  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1440x576      50.00  
   1440x480      59.94  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
   640x350       70.07  
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
USB-C-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: No, your primary screen has 50hz (check the * mark). Your secondary screen has 60hz. Depending on your GPU hardware you might have to define your primary monitor to use those 143hz. Since I don't know which distro/version you are using and since you didn't tell us if you're using wayland or XServer, I can't help any further.

Comment: @kanehekili Ah, okay thank you for breaking down some of those numbers for me. I'm not entirely sure what I'm looking at so that is helpful. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and I'm not sure if i'm using wayland or XServer.

Comment: You can check that out: `Ubuntu check if wayland` could be entered into your favorite search machine - that way you start to get a feeling how linux works. And: Add your data into your question **not into the comment* Use the [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1403402/edit) link below your question. People won't browse through the comments.

Comment: @kanehekili alright so I believe I'm running XServer and not wayland. By getting my session ID from `loginctl` which is 2, and running: loginctl show-session 2 -p Type the output I get this: `Type=x11`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you provided us with the necessary information, you could use xrandr to check if you can change your monitor:

```
xrandr --output DP-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 143.85
```

If that works you should use the nvidia-settings to create a configuration that suites your needs. nvida-settings (that I assumed from your tags) are available if the proprietary NVIDIA drivers are installed (Ubuntu hardware app)

NVIDIA has written some good [solution](https://docs.nvidia.com/drive/drive_os_5.1.6.1L/nvvib_docs/index.html#page/DRIVE_OS_Linux_SDK_Development_Guide/Windows%20Systems/window_system_x11.html) about persisting (i.e make your settings stay for the next boot) the information you need for your monitors. It also explains why NVIDIA doesn't set the frequency of your monitor right.

The conf file produced by this tool should be saved as file:

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/21-nvidia.conf
```

Reboot. In case that configuration is somehow crappy and your desktop won't start, open a terminal (crtl+alt+f2), login and remove that file. The next reboot (the command is ... `reboot`) should restore you to your fuzzy monitor.